# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist (even when kept in java folder)

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

My problem is similar to [this](http://Spring%20cannot%20find%20bean%20xml%20configuration%20file%20when%20it%20does%20exist) but i am not able to solve it even after following solutions mentioned. Moreover i am getting `true` output for

```
File f = new File("src/main/java/resources/beans.xml");
System.out.println("Exist test: " + f.exists());
```

Please see screenshot provided at the bottom.

What is failing :
Wherever I am keeping my beans.xml and providing the path in different ways, it's always giving java.io.FileNotFoundException.

What I tried : After going through similar problems on web I kept beans.xml in every possible folder and wrote path in every possible way but still got same error. For example after reading most popular approach I placed beans.xml file under java folder. Also I am directly referring to "beans.xml" in `ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");`.I tried other ways to, for example creating resources folder and then keeping beans.xml in it. But still same error.

Following is screenshot for one of the case :
[error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTBfX.png)

following are the errors :

```
icked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
Feb 06, 2022 7:46:53 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@179d3b25: startup date [Sun Feb 06 19:46:53 IST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 06, 2022 7:46:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 13 more
```

Following is my beans.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="vehicle" class="org.example.Bike"></bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: `src/main/resources/beans.xml`, so create a resources directory. Maven separates these.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes I tried that too(I have mentioned in problem description). Didn't worked.

Comment: @JoopEggen See here i have tried https://ibb.co/SQg818M

Comment: Note that I am using intellij and based on my previous experience it's notoriously difficult  and produces uncertain things.